# How to define a wrapper around the xparse \NewDocumentCommand command?

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I often want to define a command (using xparse) like the following

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Comon}{oo}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \mathsf{Mod}
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            \mathsf{Mod}_{#1}
        }{
            \mathsf{Mod}_{#1}(#2)
        }
    }
}
```

so that the same command name `\Mod` with different numbers of optional arguments displays differently.

Ideally, I'd be able to write my own command `\NewCommandAlts` which would be called like

```
\NewCommandAlts{\Mod}{2}
    {\mathsf{Mod}}
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}}
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}(#2)}
```

and would define a command `\Mod` that is equivalent to the one defined above.

The best that I have is

```
\newcommand{\NewCommandAltsTwo}[4]{
    \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{oo}{
        \IfNoValueTF{##1}{#2}{\IfNoValueTF{##2}{#3}{#4}}
    }
}

\NewCommandAltsTwo{\Mod}
    {\mathsf{Mod}}
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}}
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}(#2)}
```

which works. Any ideas for how to write the case that handles any number of arguments?

Comment: Your code compiles, the issue lies elsewhere in the document you tested it in.

Comment: are you sure you want more than two optional arguments? even two is hard to use `\Mod[a][b][c][d]`  is impossible to read and you can't not supply a if you want to supply d, at that stage it's better to use a different syntax such as `\mod[field=2, value=42, whatever=something,...]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is a simple remedy to this problem: you can simply alter the function signature to add otherwise ignored mandatory arguments in-between: `\Mod[a]{}[b]{}[c]{}[d]`. ;-))

Comment: You can also use different delimiters like `\NewDocumentCommand\splat{d<> o}`... `\splat<one>[two]`.

Comment: @Rmano that's highly discouraged syntax :P

Comment: @Skillmon oh --- I quite like it... ;-) (too much `beamer`?)

Comment: @Skillmon Not at all: `d` and `D` are among the allowed argument types. Don't confuse them with `g` and `G`.

Comment: @egreg `d` and `D` might be allowed, but it was my understanding that the delimiters should be used consistently, and that would be brackets for ordinary optional arguments. If anything I'd go for an embellishment for the subscript argument in this question, but certainly not to `<>` for what seems like a completely normal optional argument.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the k-th optional argument is specified only in case the previous (k-1) optional arguments were specified, too, you can do something like this:

```latex
\newcommand\Firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\Secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\NewCommandAlts[2]{%
  \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\Firstoftwo#2{}{}}$\expandafter\Firstoftwo\else\expandafter\Secondoftwo\fi
  {\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}{}}%
  {\NewCommandAltsReverseLoop{0}{#1}{}{}#2{}{}\NewCommandAlts{}}%
}%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\NewCommandAltsReverseLoop{%
  \long\def\NewCommandAltsReverseLoop#1#2#3#4#5#6\NewCommandAlts#7{%
    %#1 amount of items processed so far.
    %#2 command to define
    %#3 o-collection
    %#4 reversed list
    %#5 this item
    %#6 remaining items
    %#7 array of argument-numbers.
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\Firstoftwo#6{}{}}$\expandafter\Firstoftwo\else\expandafter\Secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \expandafter\NewCommandAltsLoop\expandafter{\Firstoftwo{}#3}{#2}{}#4{}{}\NewCommandAlts{0}#7\NewCommandAlts
    }{%
      \expandafter\NewCommandAltsReverseLoop\expandafter{\number\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3o}{{#5}#4}#6\NewCommandAlts{{#1}#7}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\NewCommandAltsLoop{%
  \long\def\NewCommandAltsLoop#1#2#3#4#5\NewCommandAlts#6#7\NewCommandAlts{%
    %#1 o-collection
    %#2 command to define
    %#3 result
    %#4 this item
    %#5 remaining items
    %#6 this argument number
    %#7 remaining argument-numbers
    \ifcat$\detokenize{#5}$\expandafter\Firstoftwo\else\expandafter\Secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \NewDocumentCommand{#2}{#1}{#3}%
    }{%
      \ifnum#6=0 \expandafter\Firstoftwo\else\expandafter\Secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \NewCommandAltsLoop{#1}{#2}{#4#3}#5\NewCommandAlts#7\NewCommandAlts
      }{%
        \NewCommandAltsLoop{#1}{#2}{\IfNoValueTF{###6}{#4}{#3}}#5\NewCommandAlts#7\NewCommandAlts
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\NewCommandAlts{\Mod}{%
    {\mathsf{Mod}} % Tokens in case no optional arguments
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}} % Tokens in case one optional argument
    {\mathsf{Mod}_{#1}(#2)} % Tokens in case two optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case three optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case four optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case five optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case six optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case seven optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case eight optional arguments
    %{...} % Tokens in case nine optional arguments
}%

% \expandafter\show\csname Mod code\endcsname
% \ShowDocumentCommandArgSpec\Mod

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$\Mod$

$\Mod[A]$

$\Mod[A][B]$

\end{document}
```

[image]